# How do I create an clickable icon that shows a datepicker with multi date picker?

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue.js project . I'd like to have an icon displaying a calendar, and when you click on the icon , you'll get a datepicker to choose multi date from.

How do I implement that?

I've looked at the docs:

and I've tried something like this:

````
                align="right"
                v-model="test"
              icon="calendar"
                :lang="lang"
                :multi="multi"
                :always-display="false"
            
              >
              </m-date-picker>```
but that doesn't working
What am I missing?
````

Comment: Why don't you use the html property html type date ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.